# Clearing values for left, right etc

Tags: css

Say I have an element with position absolute, with a value set for left;

```
#myElement {position:absolute; left:20px; top:0}
```

If I need to have a class which I can apply to shift the element to the other side I might define something like

```
#myElement.right {right:20px;}
```

But is there a way I can clear the value for left:20px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left: inherit`?

Comment: bingo plus sme characters to fill space

Answer (score 0):

Or use sensible classes:

```
#myElement { position: absolute; top: 0; }
#myElement.left { left: 20px; }
#myElement.right { right:20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

to clear or reset an absolute position you can use `auto` as value.

```
#myElement.right {right:20px;left:auto;}
```